# How to place tabbar controller in second view in viewbased application?

Tags: iphone

I am very new to iPhone world. I am working on a view based project.MY first view have login page. when  login is successful it moves to next view.
What i want to implement is that when i will be at second view. There will be a tabbarcontroller which have five tab items and first tab's view will be visisble. When i click other tabs, we will get next views accordingly.

Now, How to place a tab bar in second view only ?

Any kind of help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [self presentModalViewController to show the login controller over your tabbar controller. After successfull login, just dismiss it.

Comment: thanks, but this will create my login on tabbar which i do not want. My login will be different and after login next view will have tabbar . Hope i am very clear what i need. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you mean your login does not cover the entire screen? Because that's just what is it supposed to do. Can you post the code you use to present the modal controller?

Comment: either in app delegate, or in viewDidAppear of the view used as default (i.e. the one that shows right after app is started.)

Answer (score 1):

You would need to create a ViewController which is a subclass of UITabBarViewController. Design the tabbar in nib or view lifecycle method of this controller.

After login present the new controller as [self presentModalViewController]

Answer (score 1):

```
You need to implement your code as below.
First create a controller class for login.

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [self generateLoginScreen];

    [self removeLoginScreen]; // On login check implement this method or u can directly write the snippet here as well.



    [self prepareControllersOnTabs];  //your tab controller code function

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}

-(void) removeLoginScreen
{
    [loginScreenViewController.view removeFromSuperview];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
    [loginScreenViewController release];
}

-(void) generateLoginScreen
{
    loginScreenViewController = [[LoginScreenController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LoginScreenController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

    [self.window addSubview:self.loginScreenViewController.view];
}

Hope this is exactly what u want.
```